# Custom Average function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time-series

I have time series data, 20 rows 30 columns, the first column is the name of the field for which I am noting down the time spent, that is something like,

```
Field Name
----------
A
B
C
```

second column is the sum,

```
Sum
---
10:00
5:00
2:00
```

third column is the average,

```
Average
-------
1:00
0:30
0:10
```

and the rest of the columns are time series data, for time spent like,

```
09-Aug-2022
-----------
2:00
0:20
0:05
```

now, when computing the average, I divide the sum by (today() - first_day_in_the_time_series()),
(currently for all three field names A, B and C it is `today() - 23-June-2022`), but instead of this first day in the time series, I want the first time an entry is present in the time series data.

so for `A` it could be `today() - 23-June-2022`, for `B` it could be `today() - 30-June-2022`, that is the first time the particular field has an entry in the time series data

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Since Excel time is stored as numbers couldn't you just use Min to get the earliest time instead of using Today?

Comment: today() has to be there, what I am creating a time series is for time spent browsing a particular app on my phone, so the average should be counted from the first day I installed the app, till today. But currently I have set it as today() - 23-June-2022. Instead of 23-Jun-2022, it should be the day a particular app is installed, that would be the first time series entry for that particular row/app/field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the first number in a range can be achieved with this formula:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER($D2:$L2),0),0)
```

If your date series are daily, then you could simply divide your Sum by the number of days that are on your spreadsheet:

```
=$B2/((COUNT($D$1:$L$1)-MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER($D2:$L2),0),0))+1)
```

I'm not sure your idea of calculating an average from today's day is correct. If you haven't entered data for a few days, then the average will appear to drop. However, if you wish to stick with your logic, then the formula is adjusted slightly:

```
=$B3/(TODAY()-OFFSET($D$1,0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER($D3:$L3),0),0)-1))
```

You may want to dynamically size the range of the date series. I'll leave that one with you.

This assumes your date series is on row 1, starting at column D. My example only goes as far as column L

Comment: on some days, a few apps are not used at all, but those days also need to be counted to calculate the average time spent for the apps, so, I prefer the technique using today as compared to count